# How to set the transparency of the tkinter frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

Python version 2.7

Code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk();
root.geometry ('{}x{}'.format(w,h));
left_frame = Frame(root, width = w*0.8, height=400, bg='#988C89');
right_frame = Frame(root, bg='#988C89',  width = w*0.8, height=400 );


left_frame.grid_propagate(0);
right_frame.grid_propagate(0);

root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1);
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1); 

visible = Frame (root,  width = w*0.8, height=400);
visible.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="new");
```

How do I adjust the transparency of a visible frame?

If I add the code

```
 visible.attributes("transparentcolor","red")
```

I get `error : AttributeError: Frame instance has no attribute 'attributes'`

and with code

```
visible.configure(bg='#988C8900');
```

I get `error : tkinter.TclError: invalid color name "#988C8900"`

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just cannot set the transparency of the frame in tkinter. But you can set the transparency of the whole window with 
`root.attributes('-alpha', 0.5)`

You can also do `root.attributes("-transparentcolor", "red")` if you are using Windows, but again it will be applied to the whole window.

Otherwise, you can overlay PNG images with transparent parts using a `Canvas`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when it was introduced, but at least since tk 8.5 (which was the tk version with python 2.7), you can set the [background](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/frame.html#M-background) of a Frame or LabelFrame to an empty string,

```
Frame(root, background='')
```

and it will be transparent, as in it will show the bottom widgets, including a background image if there is one, unlike `root.attributes` making the whole window actually transparent.

Here's an example showing that the frame actually shows the background image (created using a Label) when the background is set to an empty string. The frame is just the same height as the labels.

[image: sample image showing that the frame is actually transparent]

Unfortunately, this empty string background is supported only by Frame and LabelFrame.