# How to set opacity labels in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label, opacity

I'm a new begginner programmer of Python and I want to ask something.
How can I set the background opacity of a label on Tkinter?
I searched for possible solutions but I didn't find nothing, if somebody knows how to do it, let me know. Thanks

Comment: I don't think that's possible, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271399/how-to-set-the-transparency-of-the-tkinter-frame

Comment: Relevant [updating-tkinter-label-with-an-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798496/updating-tkinter-label-with-an-image)

Comment: I think it's possible, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77850151/16813096