# TKinter make Frame transparent to show underlying widget

Tags: python, tkinter, transparency, transparent, tkinter-layout

I want to add a background image in Tkinter. I did that by using `Label`. But the problem is, I want the frames above the image to be transparent so that only the main content remains visible while I don't get the white background, I get the image. I tried using the

```
root.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', "red")
```

Way, and then assigning red as `bg` to the frame, but it makes the frame completely transparent, I can see my background applications instead of the underlying image. Here is what I am getting:
[image]
But I want the below image to continue above.
Here is my code for adding the label background

```
image = Image.open("grocery-cart-with-item-1005638.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image, master=root)
bg_label = Label(root, image=photo)
bg_label.image = photo
bg_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

And here is the code for the main Frame which contains the graph and the heading for the graph:

```
frame = Frame(root,name="mainframe",bg="red")
frame.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)
```

How do I get the frame to be transparent so that the Label which has the image is visible

Comment: @stovfl none of them solves my problem though

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set the transparency of the tkinter frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271399/how-to-set-the-transparency-of-the-tkinter-frame)

Comment: @stovfl I mentioned in the question, I already used the `wm_attributes`. It is showing my other programs

Comment: ***" I already used the wm_attributes"***: That's not the point, you didn't read the given linked answer.